# Request for member 'direction 'in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

[self showImageWithText:@"swipe" atPoint:location];

    if ([recognizer direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        location.x -= 220.0;
    }
    else {
        location.x += 220.0;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
    myimage.alpha = 0.0;
    myimage.center = location;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: What is the full error message from the console and which like is it occurring on? Are you using ARC? You can just edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 1):

Either the class instance that `recognizer` is an instance of is not valid or that class does not have a method `direction`. It might be invalid if it has not been instantiated or because it no longer points to a valid object, perhaps released and dealloced.